# Como Inserir na tabela se o registro não existir

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Como inserir na tabela se não existir o registro, como por exemplo existe a tabela turma_materia, tem as seguintes informações:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | turma | materia |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  |  1    |  1      |
| 2  |  1    |  2      |
| 3  |  2    |  2      |
```

Ai se tentar inserir a materia 1 com a turma 1 ele vai verificar se tem, se não tiver dar o insert, se tiver não ele não inseri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `SELECT` ao invés de `VALUES` no `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO turma_materia(ID, turma, materia)
SELECT 1, 1, 1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM turma_materia
                    WHERE ID = 1
                      AND turma = 1
                      AND materia = 1);
```

Se quiser definir apenas uma vez os valores, você pode utilizar uma `subquery` no `FROM`:

```
INSERT INTO turma_materia(ID, turma, materia)
SELECT x.ID, x.turma, x.materia
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS ID,
               1 AS turma,
               1 AS materia) x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM turma_materia tm
                    WHERE tm.ID = x.ID
                      AND tm.turma = x.turma
                      AND tm.materia = x.materia);
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: Melhor seria um índice UNIQUE, não?

Comment: @Bacco opa, não tinha visto o comentário. Vi agora a outra resposta, obrigado, vou dar um `UP` lá. Realmente seria a melhor solução