# Insert values x into table A if exist on table B

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, procedure

Eu quero fazer insert na tabela A do campo key, mas apenas se esse key já existir na tabela B

Exemplo Inserir key(123) na tabela B se existir key(123) na tabela a

(estou usando procedures do sql managemente studio)

---

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertHeartRate]
(

    @TimeStamp datetime = '',
    @Value varchar(3) = '',
    @MacAddress varchar(30) = ''
)
as
BEGIN
    Insert into HeartRate (TimeStamp,Value,MacAddress)
    Select @MacAddress
    where (Select @MacAddress
                From banda
                where MacAddress= @MacAddress);
    Values(@TimeStamp,@Value,@MacAddress)
    
END
```

estou tentando alterar o procedure, mas com dificuldades, o tal key seria o macaddress

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como Inserir na tabela se o registro não existir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299119/como-inserir-na-tabela-se-o-registro-n%c3%a3o-existir)

Comment: obrigado,mas não, eu quero inserir na tebela a, mas so quando a key 123 ja EXISTE na tabela b.

Comment: e não é isso que a resposta mostra mas com um "não" existir? se tirar o `not` que tem no `not exists` não vai fazer exatamente o que quer?

Comment: sim pensei nessa opção, mas caso o valor não exista ele deixa inserir?

Comment: faça um teste :) além disso, coloque na sua pergunta uma tag com o banco de dados que está usando

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
Insert into HeartRate (TimeStamp, Value, MacAddress)
    Select top(1) @TimeStamp, @Value, @MacAddress
    From banda
    where MacAddress = @MacAddress
```

O Select só vai retornar algum dado se existir alguma linha na tabela Banda com o valor do parâmetro para a coluna MacAddress, sendo que não será inserida nenhuma linha se não for retornado nenhum dado. E você pode remover o top(1) caso exista sempre só uma linha na tabela Banda para cada MacAddress.

Espero que ajude

Comment: exatamente isso, então não necessito dos "Values"

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram, e desculpem a minha inexperiencia

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Avalie por gentileza a possibilidade de aceitar a sugestão como uma resposta